# How to center text vertically relative to siblings and add "connector"

Tags: html, css

I have the following markup (which can change) with [Plunkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/ltO8xkUja0QHadvnyFut?p=preview):

```
  <div class="block-group">
    <div class="block-operator">And</div>
    <div class="block-children">
      <div class="block-group">
        <div class="block-container">number</div>
        <div class="block-container">&gt;</div>
        <div class="block-container">1</div>
      </div>
      <div class="block-group">
        <div class="block-container">city</div>
        <div class="block-container">=</div>
        <div class="block-container">"Testville"</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

I need to style it so it does two things:

- the "AND" element is vertically centered compared to its `block-children` siblings
- I'd like a "connector" to link the siblings to the "AND" element/text

Ultimately, it should look like this:

[image]

How can I modify my existing CSS?

Comment: what about posting your css and a working snippet?

Comment: @LuisfelipeDejesusMunoz I provided a Plunkr link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `vertical-align: middle` with child element and not with container and for the connector you may use pseudo-element and border and you can easily control its size/position:

```css
.block-group {
  border: 1px solid #999;
}

.block-operator {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  margin:0 20px;
}

.block-children {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  position:relative;
}
.block-children:before {
  content:"";
  position:absolute;
  left:-10px;
  width:20px;
  top:8px;
  bottom:8px;
  border-left:2px solid;
  border-radius:50%;
}

.block-children>div {
  display: block;
  float: none;
}

.block-container {
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  float: left;
  min-width: 40px;
  /* min-height: 30px; */
  padding: 4px;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<div class="block-group">
  <div class="block-operator">And</div>
  <div class="block-children">
    <div class="block-group">
      <div class="block-container">field.number</div>
      <div class="block-container">&gt;</div>
      <div class="block-container">1</div>
    </div>
    <div class="block-group">
      <div class="block-container">administrativeDestination.city</div>
      <div class="block-container">=</div>
      <div class="block-container">"expression.value"</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Ahh. Thanks!  Any thoughts on the "connector"?

Comment: Amazing. :) Thanks again

Comment: Any way to have the `height` be automatic in the `.block-children:before` style?

Comment: @im1dermike yes, you can set top:0 and bottom:0 and remove the height property ... you can control the height by contriling top/bottom

Comment: @im1dermike updated the code to use top/bottom instead of fixed height

Comment: Awesome.  Since you've been so helpful and while I still have your attention, I forked the Plunkr (https://plnkr.co/edit/MKPvUKIUHFuvof42WTnK?p=preview) adding another layer.  Having issues getting the operators to stay centered to the left and being indented now.  Mind taking a look?

Comment: @im1dermike the issue is that you are using inline-block element and when there is no enough space you have a line break. If you will manage to make a more complex graph, i advice you to go with flex, easier to handle : https://jsfiddle.net/kwywxpft/2/

Comment: Thank you.  I can try to do that.  The second element in the `OR` block does not wrap in your example.